# Java FX (FXML) setDisable

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have 2 buttons, one of them is Play, 2nd is Stop. If i click on Play he should be disabled and Stop should be enabled. I'm using Java FX ScreeBuilder 1.0 Why it doesn't work?

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button start;

        @FXML
    private Button stop;

    @FXML
    private void ButtonStart(ActionEvent event) {
        start.setDisable(true);
        stop.setDisable(false);
    }

    @FXML
    private void ButtonStop(ActionEvent event) {
        start.setDisable(false);
        stop.setDisable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have the Button entry in the corresponding *.fxml* file linked with the method in your controller.

In your case, these entries should look similar the following:

```
<Button fx:id="start" onAction="#ButtonStart" />
<Button fx:id="stop" onAction="#ButtonStop" />
```

Comment: got this <Button fx:id="play" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ButtonStart" text="PLAY" />
    <Button fx:id="stop" disable="true" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ButtonStop" text="STOP" />

Comment: In this case, try modifying that row to the following:

Comment: <Button fx:id="start" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ButtonStart" text="PLAY" /> <Button fx:id="stop" disable="true" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ButtonStop" text="STOP" />

Comment: The problem was that the ID value of your play button(`fx:id="play"`) was not matching the field's name(`private Button start`) in your controller class.